# Not getting spanish characters (ú, í )but getting like (Ã³ , Ã) on UI

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, character-encoding, properties-file

I declared three locale conversions in three properties files like Strings.properties, Strings_es_ES.properties and Strings_en_GB.properties ( for US, ES and UK)

In Strings_es_ES.properties,i declared the strings like below and set the properties file with UTF-8 format.

```
admin.main.numberofrewards=Número de recompensas:
admin.main.categorylist=lista Categoría
```

I am using the above resource bundle in .jsp files like below

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<h2><spring:message code="admin.main.numberofrewards"/></h2>
<p><spring:message code="admin.main.categorylist"/></p>
```

I am getting output  on the browser like below

```
NÃ³mero de recompensas
lista CategorÃa
```

Please help me on this

Comment: Please format your post properly

Comment: How have you configured your MessageSource?  If you don't specifically configure otherwise I think `.properties` files are expected to be in ISO-8859-1 encoding, not UTF-8.  You may wish to consider running them through `native2ascii` as part of your build process as this guarantees they'll be read correctly whatever encoding the loader uses.

Answer (score 10):

> *and set the properties file with UTF-8 format*

There's your mistake.

Until Java 9 they are by default read as ISO-8859-1 (at the time of writing of this question, the latest available Java version is 7, so the asker is definitely not yet using Java 9).

The [`java.util.Properties` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) says the following:

> ... the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding ...

They should therefore be saved as ISO-8859-1. If you intend to present characters which are not available by the [ISO-8859-1 character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1#Codepage_layout), then you have basically 4 options:

1. Use `native2ascii` tool to convert an UTF-8 saved properties file to an ISO-8859-1 encoded properties file with unicode escapes in form of `\uXXXX` over all place instead of those "special characters" which are not covered by ISO-8859-1 charset.
2. Use an properties file editor which is capable of doing #1 automagically, such as the one built in Eclipse. In other words, just create and edit the properties file in Eclipse. It'll worry automagically about the encoding.
3. Use a custom [`ResourceBundle.Control`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) implementation wherein you explicitly read the properties file yourself using `new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")`. However, as non-Spring-user I have no clue how to tell Spring to use that custom `Control`. [In JSF it's easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645491/i18n-with-utf-8-encoded-properties-files-in-jsf-2-0-appliaction/3646601#3646601).
4. Upgrade to Java 9 or newer, which reads them as UTF-8 by default. This way you can safely save them as UTF-8.

#### See also:

- [Internationalization in a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183245/internationalization-in-a-website/2458938#2458938)
- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](https://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your property file looks like this `Descripción de artículos` but you are getting this on the front-end `DescripciÃ³n de artÃ­culos`, then the problem is the encoding used to read your property file, here is how you can tell Spring to always use UTF-8:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;

@Configuration
public class MessageConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        // other config options go here if needed, e.g. path to the property bundle
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```